# Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response while sending back nested JSON value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function, which is returning me a value from dynamdb table. The value is in nested jason format.

When I test the lambda in it's own console it is working fine.
BUT
When I integrate it with API gateway it is giving me an internal server error with this message.

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
```

here is my response body

```
 return {
            "isBase64Encoded": "true",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
            "body": response
        }
```

Does anyone know this issue.

I tried with

```
return {
            "isBase64Encoded": "true",
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
            "body": json.dumps(response['Items'])
        }
```

it seems to be working.

What is the issue causing this? because if I have a normal JSON.

```
"body": response
```

works properly. The issue only comes when there is nested JSON

Here is the JSON object:

```
[
   {
      "time_stamp":"2021-01-13 06:02:42",
      "broker_id":"broker1",
      "load_id":"ab6fd05f-3f54-44dc-ae6d-28e924fe1ae2",
      "messages":[
         {
            "date":"22:32",
            "messanger_id":"carrier@abc.com",
            "message":"Hello",
            "user":"carrier"
         },
         {
            "date":"22:35",
            "messanger_id":"broker@abc.com",
            "message":"Hi",
            "user":"broker"
         }
      ],
      "carrier_id":"carrier1"
   },
   {
      "time_stamp":"2021-01-13 06:03:32",
      "broker_id":"broker1",
      "load_id":"ab6fd05f-3f54-44dc-ae6d-28e924fe1ae2",
      "messages":[
         {
            "date":"22:32",
            "messanger_id":"carrier@abc.com",
            "message":"Hello",
            "user":"carrier"
         },
         {
            "date":"22:35",
            "messanger_id":"broker@abc.com",
            "message":"Hi",
            "user":"broker"
         }
      ],
      "carrier_id":"carrier2"
   }
]
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your `response` object?

Comment: @Marcin hope your doing well and safe, 
I have added a json example in the qustion

Comment: Hi. Im fine. Are you sure this is correct response? It does not have any `Items`, but you are using `response['Items']`?

Comment: I have given you the response['Items'] itself. 
but it works only with lambda but when I integrate it with API gateway I get the above-mentioned error

Comment: But in your question you write that `"body": response` does not work, not `"body": response["Items"]`? Can you clarify please what works, what does not, and what is the example you provided.

Comment: @Marcin when i json serialize it with "json.dumps(response['Items])" it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with `json.dumps` because you are getting **JSON string**, which is required for proxy lambda integration. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html):

> With the Lambda proxy integration, the Lambda function **must** return output of the following format:

```
{
    statusCode: "...",            // a valid HTTP status code
    headers: { 
        custom-header: "..."      // any API-specific custom header
    },
    body: "...",                  // a JSON string.
    isBase64Encoded:  true|false  // for binary support
}
```

As you can see `JSON string` must be used in `body`. You can't return plain json object as you do when you write `"body": response['Items']`

Comment: could you help me out of this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913827/how-to-have-set-up-stage-in-api-gateway-to-have-resources-pointing-to-different