# How to have set up Stage in API gateway to have resources pointing to different lambda in different stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I was wondering what is the exact functionality of the "Stage" in the API gateway console.

What I am trying to achieve is.
To have the same resources with the same HTTP methods point to different lambda function in different stages.

[image: resource]

[image: stage]

my development URL point to my development lambda and my production URL point to the production lambda.

will it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible through [stage variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html). The variables allow you to invoke different functions depending on the used stage. This is exemplified in:

- [Call a Lambda function through an API with a stage variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/amazon-api-gateway-using-stage-variables.html#call-api-lambda-backend-with-stage-variable)

What's more, you could invoke same function, but with different parameters that depend on the stage:

> For example, you might want to **reuse the same Lambda function for multiple stages in your API**, but the function should read data from a different Amazon DynamoDB table depending on which stage is being called.

Technically, a stage [is](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-stages.html) a **snapshot of the API**. It is something similar to [versions of a lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html), where different versions represent different snapshots of your function. The exception in API is, that the API stages can be modified, whereas versions of a lambda function are immutable.

Comment: could you help me out of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933833/cloudfront-is-giving-your-connection-is-not-private-error