# cloudfront is giving "your connection is not private" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to have to host on my s3 bucket which is attached to CloudFront distribution in the front.

But I am getting this error when I access the CloudFront domain name

[image]

I know the following error might be because of the SSL certificate.
But I have the same SSL certificate attached to other distributions and that is working fine.
I also check if the name c name matches, which I does.

Could anyone help me out with this?

[image]

Comment: Have you selected redirection of http to https in CloudFront?

Comment: @Marcin yes i have

Comment: Can you double check and show how did you define your cache behavior, especially "Viewer Protocol Policy"?

Comment: @Marcin added in the question

Comment: This looks fine. So which url are you using? You wrote something about ssl certificate? Do you have your own custom domain setup for the CF distro?

Comment: i have not attached to CF to a domain yet. 
I was testing it from the domain name generated by the CF it self

Comment: @Marcin i created another SSL certificate and this seems to be working

Comment: Did you modify the domain registered in the ssl?

Comment: @Marcin I created the SSL domain with the domain name I am using